# some calculative normal distribution problem to help my daughter

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

It is known that the diameter of a fig-tree is normally distributed with $\mu=50$ cm, $\sigma=12$ cm.

$(1)$ What is the prob, that a randomly selected fig-tree has diameter $>73cm$?

$(2)$ what proportion of fig-trees have a diameter between 40 and 55 cm?

$(3)$ Find the diameter $d$, such that the $30\%$ of the fig trees exceeds the diameter $d$.

Here is what I tried:

So $1$. $\mathbb P(X>73)= \frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{73}^{\infty} e^-{\frac{(x-50)^2}{2\times 144}}$ , right? But I am not able to perform next few steps of this integration to get the final answer, could someone direct me some easy and quick way if exists?

$2.$ $\mathbb P(40<X<55)= \frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{40}^{55} e^-{\frac{(x-50)^2}{2\times 144}}$ , right? But I am not able to perform next few steps of this integration to get the final answer, could someone direct me some easy and quick way if exists?

$3.$ I absolutely do not understand the question so far, Thanks for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Standardize to use printed normal table: $P(D > 73) = P((D-50)/13 = (73-50)/13) = P(Z > 1) = 0.1587,$ where $Z$ is standard normal. which you can find from printed table of standard normal CDF. (b) Requires subtraction of two probabilities, similarly obtained. Answ for (c) from R statistical software is 70th percentile of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50,\sigma=15);$ In R, `qnorm(.75, 50, 13)` returns $58.76837.$ You can use printed normal tables to get approx answ. Look for value nearest .7000 in body of table and read z-value from margins, convert to D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ does not have analytical solution, but has been well studied with definition of some special functions such as the $erf(x)$ and $erfc(x)$ defined as

$erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\space dt $,

$erfc(x) = 1-erf(x)$.

MATLAB has these functions and can be used to solve your first two problems.

Your last problem asks you to find out the value of $d$, such that

$\frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{d}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-50)^2}{2\times 144}} dx=0.3$

MATLAB also has the inverse functions 'erfinv' and 'erfcinv' which can be used to solve this problem.

If you use MATLAB, type 'help erf' (or other function name) to get more information about how to use these functions.